# UISearchBar use multiple words for different values, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, filter

I am trying to add a search bar to my app, I can successfully filter an array of dictionay based on 1 value but I want to be able to add 2 words. For example:

```
var posts = [[String: Any]]()
var filteredData = [[String: Any]]()

posts = [[shape: square, color: red][shape: circle, color: blue][shape: square, color: blue].
```

If I search square then my results only show 1st and 3rd array, If I write blue it will show the 2nd and 3rd array, but if I write square red it doesn't show anything.

How can I search and filter multiple values? so if I write square there are 2 results and then adding red reduces it to 1 result.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredData = posts.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let shape: NSString = text["shape"] as! NSString
        let color: NSString = text["color"] as! NSString

        let rangeShape = shape.contains(searchText)
        let rangeColor = features.contains(searchText)

        return rangeShape || rangeColor
    })

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSString`? Swift `String` lets you see if a one string is contained in another.

Comment: I tried string but it gives me an error and prompts me to change to NSString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By splitting the search text using space and search all the elements in all the posts to filter.

```
let splitText = text.split(separator: " ")
let filteredData = posts.filter {
    if let s = $0["shape"] as? String, splitText.index(of: Substring(s)) != nil {
        return true
    }    
    if let s = $0["color"] as? String, splitText.index(of: Substring(s)) != nil {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

And as all other mentioned you should use `String` in swift not `NSString`.

Comment: This won't work since `text` will be equal to `"square red"`.

Comment: @maddy! Yeah I missed that. But updated it now with "square red" case.

Comment: You are now splitting `text` twice for each object in `posts`. That's pretty inefficient.

Comment: thank you for your time on this, I added the code but now I get this error,  `Insert ', whereSeparator: <#((key: String, value: Any)) throws -> Bool#>'` I get this on line `let splitText = text.split(separator: " ")`

Comment: I figured this out, I realized your text.split was referring to searchBar.text so now this has no errors and it is filtering with spaces but it is showing all that has the same shape even if the colour is different. I need it to only show the shape with the shape and colour, not the shape and a different colour